# WebSphere - MQ Status

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to fetch some information/data from (IBM) Websphere MQ using C#.
I did manage to get a message, but i can't figure out how to get details about the queue (e.g. are there any items, how many items are contained, etc).
Not Sure if it matter, but i use MQ 6.1 - the online API for c# provided by IBM is quite empty.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you want is available as [queue object properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un11000_.htm).  Some properties are settable, all are gettable.  The app needs to have inquire and/or set rights on the queue in order for these to work.

The link you provided in the comment to Stephen's response is to a different section of the WMQ .Net manual.  I suspect you are viewing it with curl or otherwise have script disabled or else you would have easily found the section I linked to above in the navigation panel.  Any page loaded in a suitable browser will reload itself inside the navigation frame and display a table of contents on the left.  The table of contents will be positioned on the page opened.  The section you referenced was to compiling the .Net app but there is a complete API reference elsewhere.

I would recommend viewing the Infocenter in a Javascript-enabled browser with cookies, or else installing the local version of the Infocenter as an Eclipse workbench.  The local version has the ability to pull down updates when the online manuals are updated.  In either case, a navigation panel is provided which includes the complete set of WMQ manuals and is searchable across all of them, by individual book or by section within a book.

The landing page for WMQ documentation [is here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/library/).  This page contains links to the online Infocenters for v6 and v7, the downloadable Infocenters for v6 & v7 and the PDF versions of the older documentation.

**EDIT - The drill-down path to definitions of the constants**

- From the MQC page readers are directed to the [Application Programming Reference manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc/fr10120_.htm) rather than directly to the MQC docs.  However, the page displayed does not represent the whole APRM content!  Click the plus sign in the navigation frame to open the TOC for the book.
- The page Constants has no content other than to direct the reader to the Constants manual.  Unfortunately, it's not linked but the manual is listed in the navigation frame simply as "[Constants](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaq.doc/fc10120_.htm)".  Click the plus sign to expand the TOC.
- This level contains the major sections of the book, one of which is the detail of all the constants under the heading of "[Constants](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaq.doc/fccontop.htm)".  Clicking that link opens an index page with all of the constants listed and links to a dedicated page for each.

Comment: I am using a quite up to date browser, my point is that the MQC documentation is missing for .NET! Your link leads to the Q documentation, but i want the MQC Struct/Enum ;)

Comment: OK, I've updated the response with the path through the nav frame to the constants.  Part of the problem is they linked to the top page of the APRM which is, as you say, quite empty.  But drilling down in that manual TOC reveals a page for constants...which links back to another stand-alone manual with all the constants.  It's a roundabout path and not easy to follow but it is vastly improved in the v7 manual.  Since V6 End-of-Life is Sept 2011 I'm guessing the structure of the v6 manuals will not be overhauled to address this.

Comment: BTW - I linked to "Q" because your question states "I can't figure out how to get details about the queue" and does not mention MQC at all.  If I'd realized that'd cost me a downvote, I'd have provided the links straight to the constants!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used XMS: The IBM Message Service Client for .NET.  The current version can be found at: [IBM Message Service Client](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24011756).  You can also find a quick tutorial at [C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pk_khuman/AquickstartCsharpWebsphereMQ07112006024017AM/AquickstartCsharpWebsphereMQ.aspx)

In general you want to follow the pattern:

```
MQCONN 
MQOPEN the queue
loop
  MQGET from the queue
  Process the message
end loop
```

Make sure you specify MQGMO_WAIT on the MQGET call.  You don't want to just poll the queue.

I'll try to find some source code when I get to the office.

Comment: I'm far beyond the quick start, i need to querry informations about the q. I got an api from IBM but its not documented. Especially the discribtion of MQC is missing -> http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10670_.htm. The Links below leads to a quite empty page...

Comment: Still no luck finding my code - The power is out, so no TFS access.  This redbook is old: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247012.html but it is what I used.  I seem to recall that I had to drop down to the c api and use interop to get it to work on 6.1.